# 巨大なコンテナイメージを高速に起動したい

Tags: aws, docker, google-cloud-platform

個人開発で趣味のサービスを作ろうと思っていまして、コンテナのデプロイ周りに関して知見をお借りしたいです。
Counter Strike 2というゲームの試合サーバーのデプロイに関してです。

- コンテナイメージのサイズが33Gbほどある
- パフォーマンスが高めのマシンが必要(c5.xlarge)
- 料金上の理由から常時起動はしたくない
- ただし、必要となったタイミングで爆速(3分以内?)で起動したい
- 必要となる数が流動的なので、一定数確保して必要な時に起動という手法は嫌いたい
- GCE, EC2だと、イメージから直接起動した場合pullする時間がかかるので起動までの時間がかかりすぎる
- イメージを保持したスナップショットから新規にインスタンスを起動すれば爆速だが、不定期にイメージをアップデートする必要があるので嫌いたい(結構頑張れば自動化は可能な範囲)

この条件を満たす設計は可能でしょうか？
自分の知識では、前述したとおり「スナップショットを定期的にメンテナンスし、それを起動する」以外の方法を思いつきませんでした。
よろしければ、皆さんの知恵をお借りしたいです。
よろしくお願いします。

edit: また、AWSでは、スナップショットから復元した場合S3からのコピーが発生しサーバーのパフォーマンスが低下するため、EBS FSRの利用が必須でした。
GCPでの場合、復元直後でもパフォーマンスの劣化が存在しないため問題なく利用が可能です。

Comment: すみません、質問後にVPC中にDockerRegistryをセルフホストしてキャッシュを持たせる方法を発見しました。後ほど検証します。

https://blog.jp.square-enix.com/iteng-blog/posts/00029-easy-private-container-cache-registry/

Comment: 別々に解決すべき複数の課題が混在してしまっているように見えます。「高速に起動」「必要時のみ起動」「不定期にイメージを更新」

Comment: 相互に関連しかつトレードオフの関係にある要件または制約事項は普通は｢別々に解決すべき課題」とは考えません。それぞれの項目は個別に考えれば課題ですらなく(すでに答えも書かれている)、他の項目と同時に成立させないといけないという条件があるから課題になっています。

Answer (score 0):

GoogleCloudPlatformのサービスで、GoogleCloudRUNというのがあります。
これは、Dockerコンテナを実行するサービスで、リクエストがないときは停止し、
リクエストが増えたときは、リクエスト数に応じた数のコンテナを起動するものです。
料金はGCEより、安くなる傾向があります。
参考になりますでしょうか。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！
ゲームの都合上、UDP接続にしか対応しておらず、CloudRunの場合UDPには対応していないため今回の場合では採用ができませんでした。